# c# Searching for a file which the user has typed in

Tags: c#, file, search

I want my program to read the input from the user and then get that input and find the file which they have asked for.

My code:

```
fileName = Console.ReadLine();
if(File.Exosts(fileName)){

do something
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be file _Exosts_?

Comment: What do you want to do with the file?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  foreach (String s in Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)){
   if(fileName.Equals(s)){
    //do something
   }else{
   MessageBox.Show("File not found in "+targetDirectory);
   }
  }
```

[Directory.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx)